# Affect value in R dataframe without checking if the index is empty

Tags: r, dataframe

```
 df = data.frame(A=c(1,1),B=c(2,2))
 df$C = NA
 df[is.na(df$B),]$C=5
```

Each time I want to affect a new value and the indexes found out to be empty like here `is.na(df$B)` , R raised raises an error `replacement has 1 row, data has 0`.
Is there a way that R just doesnt affect anything in these case instead of raising an error ?

Comment: Have you tried `df[is.na(df$B),]$C` by itself? I've never seen that technique before, typically I've seen akrun's notation of `df$C[is.na(...)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a single line instead of assigning 'C' to `NA` and then subsetting the data.frame.  The below code will assign 5 to 'C' where there are `NA` elements in 'B' or else it will be `NA`

```
df$C[is.na(df$B)] <- 5
```